# Django: How to save data in two models(tables) from one POST request?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

**I want to save data in two models from a single POST request.**
Two models (ModelA, ModelB) have the same structures.

The request passes through RESTful API using Django-Rest-Framework.

I tried putting `update_or_create()` into `def perform_create()` like below, but it failed. 
Because, it required that each input data should be `Model` instance.
I don't know how to get the instances under `def perform_create()`
Furthermore, I don't think my approach is not nice.

So I am considering another way, such as django signals(post_save, pre_save, etc.).

Please give any hints or tips.

Here's my **models.py**

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    fieldC = models.ForeignKey(ModelC)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    fieldC = models.ForeignKey(ModelC)
```

**views.py**

```
class View(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ModelA_Serializer
    queryset = ModelA.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):

        #######################################################
        ### I tried update_or_create ModelB, but it failed.####
        ### And, It's not nice way.############################
        #######################################################

        fieldC_req = int( self.request.POST.get('fieldC') )
        ModelB.objects.update_or_create(user=self.request.user, fieldC=fieldC_req)

        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ModelA_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Django signal post_save() will essentially duplicate your data

Well, first of all, you suggested the use of a Django `post_save` signal which will essentially duplicate the value from `Model1.field` to `Model2.field` (because `post_save` is called on each save).

**If that is the effect you're going for**, it would be a lot better if you stored that field in a single "shared" model, you don't want duplicate data, you can run into inconsistencies like that, plus it just wastes CPU and storage resources.

### A REST endpoint is not necessarily tied to a (single) model

For endpoint to be well designed, it doesn't have to work on a single model 
or even a model for that matter.

If for your business logic you have to hit several models, there's no problem with using `update_or_create` on 2 models in your `perform_create()` that backs the POST request

Comment: Thank you, bakkal. As your suggestion, it was ended up inserting `ModelB.update_or_create()` in `perform_create()`. I'm gonna consider taking this function in Celery tasks. Or I think I can handle this task with MySQL trigger. I appreciate you gave me confidence.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do that with def create function in your serializers.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    modelB = ModelB.objects.create(**validated_data)
    return ModelA.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Disclosure: I have never tried this before.

Read more : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

Do Comment if this works.

Comment: Thank you, Aswin. I didn't excute this code yet... I'm not sure if it works. It dosen't seem that delcaring `modelB` in `def create()` under ModelA's serializer cannot affect to copy the data. Because I think uploading data to modelB works finally in **views.py**.